# Fix Gnome (gdm3) grahical driver

Tags: boot, gnome, reinstall

Yesterday I have installed **Gnome** on Ubuntu 16.04, and I have chosen **gdm3** choice; At next booting, the Ubuntu doesn't want to boot, it freezes on blank purple screen with Ubuntu logo, I try booting several times, but it's failed, I have also trying to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> while booting, and it freezes on This Screen

[image: This Screen]

I tried to reinstall Ubuntu using [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation), but I couldn't, It should be noted that I have used an encryption to encrypt all files.

Answer (score 0):

When you're on the purple screen, try to access any tty terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+(<kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F6</kbd>) and run:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

Then, select "lightdm" and reboot.